# Python multiprocessing with Queue (split loads dynamically)

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing to process very large number of files.
I tried to put the list of files into queue and make 3 workers split the load with a common Queue data type. However this seems not working. Probably I am misunderstanding about the queue in multiprocessing package.
Below is the example source code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue

def worker(i, qu):
    """worker function"""
    while ~qu.empty():
        val=qu.get()
        print 'Worker:',i, ' start with file:',val
        j=1
        for k in range(i*10000,(i+1)*10000): # some time consuming process
            for j in range(i*10000,(i+1)*10000):
                j=j+k
        print 'Worker:',i, ' end with file:',val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    qu=Queue()
    for j in range(100,110): # files numbers are from 100 to 110
        qu.put(j)

    for i in range(3): # 3 multiprocess
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,qu))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    p.join()
```

Thanks for the comments.
I come to know that using Pool is the best solution.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(val):
    """worker function"""
    print 'Worker: start with file:',val
    time.sleep(1.1)
    print 'Worker: end with file:',val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_list=range(100,110)
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(worker, file_list)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What output do you expect and what output are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1) you are joining only on the 3rd process

2) Why not use multiprocessing.Pool?

3) race condition on qu.get()

1 & 3)

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue

def worker(i, qu):
    """worker function"""
    while 1:
        try:
            val=qu.get(timeout)
        except  Queue.Empty: break# Yay no race condition
        print 'Worker:',i, ' start with file:',val
        j=1
        for k in range(i*10000,(i+1)*10000): # some time consuming process
            for j in range(i*10000,(i+1)*10000):
                j=j+k
        print 'Worker:',i, ' end with file:',val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    qu=Queue()
    for j in range(100,110): # files numbers are from 100 to 110
        qu.put(j)

    for i in range(3): # 3 multiprocess
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,qu))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in jobs: #<--- join on all processes ...
        p.join()
```

2)

for how to use the Pool, see:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1):

You are joining only the last of your created processes. That means if the first or the second process is still working while the third is finished, your main process is goning down and kills the remaining processes before they are finished.

You should join them all in order to wait until they are finished:

```
    for p in jobs:
        p.join()
```

Another thing is you should consider using `qu.get_nowait()` in order to get rid of the race condition between `qu.empty()` and `qu.get()`.

For example:

```
    try:
        while 1:
            message = self.queue.get_nowait()
            """ do something fancy here """ 
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
```

I hope that helps